# Is speeding tolerated in Japan?

Tags: japan, driving, traffic

Driving in Japan (Nara prefecture) as a tourist, I noticed that while the speed limits are generally very low, at least for my German feeling, nearly everyone seems to do at least some degree of speeding. On a curvy mountain road clearly marked with a 30 sign (all units kph), people were driving between 45 and 50. On a motorway with a small 70 speed limit sign mounted high on the left side, people were driving 100 to 120 in the right lane. Is speeding widely tolerated in Japan or am I misunderstanding the speed limits?

Comment: If I could read Japanese I would have posted an answer. I found this 'Although there is no official tolerance for exceeding the speed limit, most drivers in Japan tend to drive over the speed limit on major roads.' However its sources are written in Japanese. It does suggest there isn't a cultural attitude against speeding though.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**TL;DR: Yes, it's common, but exceeding the limit by more than 10 km/h risks getting stopped and fined by the police.**

Japanese speed limits are indeed very low: the kind of straight, wide country road in Hokkaido that would have a limit of 100 in Australia will be 50, and even grade-separated expressways can go as low as 80.  (Then again, hair-raising twisty mountain roads will be 40 throughout when in Australia every other hairpin bend would be plastered with 20 km/h recommended speed warnings.)  A theory I've heard advanced is that Japanese police have targets that strongly incentivize reducing highway fatalities, and lacking other levers they constantly and often successfully lobby to reduce limits.

What this means in practice is that **many people speed**.  Speeding fines only start at 10 km/h over the limit, meaning that exceeding the limit by less than 10 km/h, while technically illegal, is usually ignored.  At the other end, getting caught speeding over 30 km/h above the limit can result in formal charges and immediate license suspension.

So if/when people speed, they tend to do so in the 10-30 km/h over band, no more.  However, speed traps are quite common and typically operated by a team where one officer hides in a bush with a speed gun and their buddies catch the offenders down the road, meaning that by the time you see the police cars, it's too late.  If caught, expect hefty fines (tens of thousands of yen) and demerit points if you have a Japanese license.

In my experience, it's best to go with the flow: drive at the same speed as all the other normal drivers (not the hotheads in the right lane), slow down when they do (the regulars know where the cops lurk), and you'll be fine.  As always your mileage may vary.

Comment: And of course be sensible where you speed. Going 30 km/h over on a highway is different than going 30 km/h over in the school zone with a posted 20 km/h sign.

Comment: But if you are a tourist you are not in a hurry and you want to see the surrounding area, so maybe go bicycling or walking instead of following the car brain advice of speeding as much as the regulars do who know how the system works. An expensive speeding ticket sucks way more when you are on holiday, and police everywhere pay more attention to foreign(ers) vehicles.

Comment: @Gantendo Do rental cars in Japan have a distinctive look?

Comment: @LeeC. If you looked at me, would you think I was born in Japan with Japanese parents? You can easily distinguish between people with their roots in the Netherlands from Japanese people, right?

Comment: @LeeC. https://www.government.nl/binaries/medium/content/gallery/rijksoverheid/content-afbeeldingen/ministeries/bz/bz-blogs/2021/pascalle-grotenhuis/pascalle_grotenhuis3.jpg Which one of these people is the Dutch ambassador for Women’s Rights and Gender Equality?

Comment: @Gantendo Might be hard to tell if each of them were driving past me at 100-120 km/h and I'm prepped to look at the car rather than the driver so I can radio it to my fellow officers.

Comment: @LeeC. In the early 90s Japanese criminals decided to drive really fast so police were unable to recognize them. This worked for a few years but then Japanese police decided to also buy cars. Also, sometimes people have to slow down, especially within city limits. ;-)

Comment: @LeeC. To answer the original question: My rental car had no special features whatsoever (not even a sticker). I don't think the police can tell just by looking at the car.

Comment: @nanash1 Rental cars have a わ on the number plate next to the numbers.

Comment: @Gantendo how exactly does your reply to Lee's comment about rental cars having a distinctive look make any sense? :/

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama i wrote: "police everywhere pay more attention to foreign(ers) vehicles" but what I was trying to say was "police everywhere pay more attention to foreigners/foreign vehicles". Unfortunately I was too late to fix it. So Lee said: "Do rental cars in Japan have a distinctive look?". And I pointed out that foreigners in Japan may stand out from the crowd depending on where they are from. https://images3.memedroid.com/images/UPLOADED655/63b2fa667d44b.jpeg

Comment: @Gantendo I see. There are also a lot of us foreigners living here in Japan, though I don't think my beat up 2006 Subaru would be mistaken for a rental car anytime soon. :D

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama Weirdly, police officers in Japan pay a lot of attention to llamas despite their low crime rate and a recidivism rate of close to zero percent.

Comment: @Gantendo Haha. The police don't generally seem to pay me any attention thankfully.